# How to retrieve the time spent in user mode in a win32 process

Tags: winapi, process, time

I know that [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223(VS.85,loband).aspx) can be used to retrieve the time a process spent in *user mode* (as opposed to the time it spent in kernel mode or the time it was suspended). Unfortunately, it seems that the resolution is only 16ms (the same as `GetTickCount`).

Is there a way to retrieve the time with greater precision?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) function. But I have heard that it has problems in multi core environments, not sure though.

Comment: Naveen, thank you for answering. Unfortunately, I'm trying to get the time that the process spent in *user mode* (as opposed to the time it spent in kernel mode or the time it was suspended). QueryPerformanceCounter does not provide that.